# Dropbox refuses to start without X

Tags: dropbox, headless

Had a Dropbox install run fine for months on Debian headless server. Had to force reboot server. Now Dropbox will refuse to start without X.

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

With X it runs just fine and shows icon on Gnome panel.

I need it to run headless again. It's a server that should work "alone", without requiring a remote X display.

For a different user on the same server it runs just fine.

Any idea?

Will it be that it keeps somewhere in the config whether to use X or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The Dropbox daemon is just checking your $DISPLAY environment variable.  If you're not forwarding X over ssh, then $DISPLAY is empty.  So, even if you are connected with X Forwarding, you could do:

```
DISPLAY='' /etc/init.d/dropbox start
```

or just edit the dropboxd script in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

After completely deleting `~/.dropbox` `~/.dropbox-dist` and `~/Dropbox` I reinstalled with `dropbox start -i` and, apparently, after install it did nothing. `dropbox status` returned `Waiting to be linked to a Dropbox account...`

The trick was to run directly `.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and it answered with

```
This computer isn't linked to any Dropbox account...
Please visit https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link_nonce?nonce=xx to link this device.
```

After authorizing the computer all went fine. Could start and stop without X.

BUT when trying to manually start the daemon

```
/etc/init.d/dropbox start
```

it would complain again about not being able to connect to X :-(

The real problem was my root ssh connection had X Forwarding enabled by default and though dropbox would now work fine without X it detected the connection had X and tried to use it.

So the solution has been to remove the X Forwarding for the ssh connection used to manually start the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox daemon reads configuration settings and tries to reconnect to X like it did before. Delete its configuration for this particular user to make it forget about past and run it again. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, your answer lead me to the solution but there was another problem. See my own answer.